# Reducing audio , video size on upload Django

Tags: python, django, audio, ffmpeg, video-processing

I got a test server where I have features like uploading audio and video on a post . The feature is working perfectly but using a lot of space as some videos has more than 80MB while my system has only 1Gb of storage. How can I reduce my audio video size on upload maintaining no upload restriction. I am using Django and drf on backend . I looked into ffmpeg & pydub but couldnt find anything to reduce the audio bitrate or video quality. Is there anything else I should look into ? or ffmpeg will work (if ffmpeg works, please give me some example links so that I can implement before integrating to my test server) Thanks

Any suggestion regarding this will be helpful

Comment: I couldn't find any specific programming issue in your question that would qualify for Stack Overflow.

Comment: My apologies, I am actually new to django and backend . I am still trying and testing my knowledge in the process. I am actually looking for any python library or any source for audio , video compression on server side

Comment: Requests for libraries and other off-site resources are not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Got it . Thanks

Comment: Answer depends on the formats you are willing to support.

Comment: I am thinking of Mp3 format